# _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push Not working in firefox

Tags: 2010, javascript, spweb, spbodyonload

I tried this in firefox i dont know why its not working but it working in other browsers

```
function loadmonth() {
    alert('called');
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("loadmonth");
```

Comment: Working on fixing this right now.